# AWS volume from snapshot missing data

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, mount, amazon-ebs, ext4

This is a weird one.

On a new ec2 instance + new data volume attached at /dev/xvdb mounted with:

mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdb
mkdir /mnt/xvdb
mount -t ext4 /dev/xvdb /mnt/xvdb

I take a snapshot of /dev/xvdb -> create a new volume
Another ec2 instance + mounting the volume created from snapshot. Mount with:
mkdir /mnt/xvdb
mount -t ext4 /dev/xvdb /mnt/xvdb

I have some files missing. More specifically I'm snapshotting the data for a git server served with git http backend.

I have the branches,hooks,info,objects folder etc, but everything in those folders are empty.

Any ideas?? O_o...........

Edit- I did this test multiple timees and I get the same result every time.

Comment: That doesn't sound like the kind of thing which could happen with a snapshot - it is very likely done on a block level. Are you sure you're instantiating the latest snapshot?

Comment: @l0b0 Yes, I actually did the test repeatedly. I'm very sure it's something I'm doing wrong as I'm a linux n00b. (I was doing mkfs on the attached volume before and wondering there's no data on volume at all.)